# OLE Command Task vs OLE Destination

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS and wanted to know which would give a better performance while performing inserts in data workflow.

Are there any advantages of using one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are similarly named transformations but with vastly different uses. The Destination is what it sounds like - it's the terminus for a data flow. You can't connect anything to the output of an OLE DB Destination (beyond the error flow). The destination has the ability to perform *set* based inserts (this is very important for good performance). It can also perform singleton inserts (issue an insert statement for **each** row flowing through a data flow) which will result in lower throughput to your destination.

Contrast that behaviour with the OLE DB Command. This is a transformation component that allows you to do whatever you want for each row flowing through a data flow. It's a swiss army knife SQL "doer." You *can* use it as an INSERT statement but most commonly I see it as an UPDATE destination. For small data sets, that is fine. The cost of using the OLE DB Command transformation is cost. It will issue singleton statements for each row flowing through a data set. That's going to be costly in terms of transaction log, transaction time held, plan cache and a host of other things I can't think of. There's no way to tell SQL Server to batch up those operations so you'll be reduced to issuing a statement row by agonizing row (RBAR).

If you need to do updates in SSIS, you will get a much better performance profile by writing updates to a staging table and then performing a set based update after the data flow completes. Andy Leonard has a great series of articles discussing this pattern on his [Stairway to Integration Services series](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/76390/).

Reference

- [OLE DB Destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx)
- [OLE DB Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141138)

Answer (score 1):

An OLE Destination is the better choice for inserts because it allows for bulk loads of data into the destination table.

An OLE DB Command (which I assume is what you mean by OLE Command Task) will perform its operation row by row, which is significant slower.  Though, a OLE DB command can handle updates and deletes which a OLE Destination can't